# Positioning background image behind the text of <a> tag

Tags: html, css

I have a link with background-image set.

```
    <a href="#" style="background-image: url('bg.png')">text</a>
```

Is it possible to move background-image without moving text?

Comment: Yes it's possible to set the background image on an `<a>`, but you'll probably want to set the `display` type to `block` on the `<a>`, as it's an `inline` element by default. And `:hover`, you can add `background-position` to move the image, if it's supposed to be a sprite image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can move the image using background position:

```
<a href="#" style="background-image: url('bg.png'); background-position: -10px -10px">text</a>
```

or even better

```
<a href="#" style="background:url('bg.png') no-repeat -10px -10px;">text</a>
```

Comment: Oh, was he really asking how to position the background? :D

Comment: exactly. and sorry for my horrible English :[